# Display one column at a time

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if this is possible and how i could do this. 
I have a workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet2 has multiple columns with 50 different records. sheet1 i would like to have a play button or run button when i click "play/run" it it will have one column and that one column will display the records of each column from sheet2 until there are no more columns form sheet2. Additionally, the display will have a 5 sec interval before cycling to the next column.

i found out how to do the time interval but not the displaying

```
'time interval 
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

'displaying i have been using copy/paste but it does not work.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just set Sheet1's column A to be Sheet2 Column A, then wait, then Sheet1 Col A, equal to column B, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these procedures to the VBA module. Then add a button or textbox/etc. to the Sheet1, and right-click the shape, and choose "Assign Macro", then select the `MyButtonClick` procedure. This will associate the macro with the button.

Then, you just need to loop over the columns and copy/paste like so:

```
Sub MyButtonClick()
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim cols as Range, c as Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set cols = ws2.Range("A1:G50")  '## Modify as needed

For Each c in cols.Columns

    c.Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A1")  '## Puts the column in Sheet1, Column A
    Call WaitForIt(5)
Next

End Sub

Sub WaitForIt(seconds as Long)

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, seconds)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking!  Just curious, why you did a separate sub for the wait part?

Comment: @BruceWayne just personal preference, certainly not necessary in this very simple case, but `Wait`, if used in a larger application might use various wait times depending on when/where it's called from, etc., so IMO it's best to subroutine it and just pass the parameter. Plus, it's a good and very simple example for OP to learn about using subroutines :D

Comment: David- 
I have a followup question. So i wanted graph the data from sheet1 while it is cycling through the numbers but once i setup the graph the graph does not change. Is there a way to make it change dynamically while the data is cycling?

Comment: @Leofig123 it should be possible, give me a second to try a few things.

Comment: @Leofig123 is your chart *already* configured to pull data from the range A1:A50?  If so, the data should be updating while the macro runs (it does when I test it). If not, then you should configure the chart accordingly.

Comment: @DavidZemens IDK what happen but after i restarted it started working.
thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat minimal-VBA approach:

Say that sheet2 looks like:

[image]

then in sheet1, create a 1-cell named range `record` (cell A2 in this case):

[image]

In column B put the formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Sheet2!R"&ROW()&"C"&record,FALSE))),INDIRECT("Sheet2!R"&ROW()&"C"&record,FALSE),"")
```

and copy it down for as many rows as the longest record in sheet 2

Then -- the VBA part can just have a loop where it has the statement

```
Range("record").Value = i
```

(with an `i` that cycles through the column numbers containing records). The spreadsheet formula takes care of pulling the correct values.